# User registration and login using firebase error "Reference.push failed: second argument must be a valid function"

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, firebase-authentication

Trying to create a basic login and sign up form using javascript and jQuery with firebase email/password authentication.

However I'm receiving this error "Reference.push failed: second argument must be a valid function" in my console @ this line

```
database.ref().push(emailnew, passwordnew);
```

I've been looking here on stackoverflow and inside the firebase docs to see how to correct this issue but I am coming up empty handed. I also feel that my JS file might have more going on than necessary but I'm not sure how to simplify it. As of right now nothing is being pushed to the database. I'm not completely familiar with firebase so any added tips would be incredibly helpful, thanks.

Ideally with successful new user account creation or login, this splash page would then redirect the user to the actual app page.

Here is the form HTML

## Sign Up

```
      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Name<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="name" id="name" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="email-signup" id="emailSignup" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Set A Password<span class="req">*</span>
        </label>
        <input type="password-signup" id="passwordSignup" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <button type=""  id="signupbutton" />Get Started</button>



    </div>
    <!-- User Login Form -->
    <div id="login">   
      <h1>Welcome</h1>


        <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Email Address<span class="req"></span>
        </label>
        <input type="emailLogin" id="emailLogin" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <div class="field-wrap">
        <label>
          Password<span class="req"></span>
        </label>
        <input type="passwordLogin" id="passwordLogin" required autocomplete="off"/>
      </div>

      <p class="forgot"><a href="#">Forgot Password?</a></p>

      <button class="button button-block" id="login" />Log In</button>

      <div id=loginmessage>
      </div>
```

Here is my user.js file with firebase intergration as follows:

```
      // Initialize Firebase
      var config = {
        apiKey: 'AIzaSyBU1fYqhQrVskqgA0Okr3ZStPfYz0s3QWQ',
        authDomain: "https://lackluster-5966e.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: 'https://lackluster-5966e.firebaseio.com',
        projectId: "lackluster-5966e",
        storageBucket: 'https://lackluster-5966e.appspot.com',
        messagingSenderId: "489067404953"
      };
      firebase.initializeApp(config);


      // var firebaseref = new Firebase("https://lackluster-5966e.firebaseapp.com");
      var database = firebase.database();
      var auth = firebase.auth();
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
      console.log(config);

    var emailnew;
    var passwordnew;

    //Collect User Data from Signup
    $("#signupbutton").click(function(event){
            event.preventDefault();
    emailnew = $("#emailSignup").val();
    passwordnew = $("#passwordSignup").val();
    database.ref().push(emailnew, passwordnew); //Error occurs 
    console.log(emailnew);
    console.log(passwordnew);
      });

//Creates New User via Firebase Authentication
 var promise = auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(emailnew, passwordnew);
 promise.then(function(user) {
 user.sendEmailVerification().then(function() {
 // Email sent.
 }, function(error) {
 // An error happened.
 });

 //Sends User Info to firebase DB
user.updateProfile({
    Name: name,
    Email: emailnew  
  }).then(function() {
  // Update successful.
  }, function(error) {
  // An error happened.
 });


// Clears all of the text-boxes for user signup
  $("#emailSignup").val("");
  $("#passwordSignup").val("");


//User Login Event
var emailLogin = document.getElementById('emailLogin');
var passwordLogin = document.getElementById('passwordLogin');

$("#login").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();


 var email = emailLogin.value;
 var password = passwordLogin.value;
 var auth = firebase.auth();

 var promise = auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
 promise.catch(function (e) {
 return console.log(e.message);
  });

// //Page redirect
// firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
//   if(user) {
//     window.location = 'index.html';
//   }
//   else{
//     //Do nothing.
//   }
// });

// Authentication Listner
// Verifies that login credentials are correct otherwise returns error message
 var Message = "<div class=\"loginmessage\">" + "Login Unsuccessful" + "</div>";
 firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function (firebaseUser) {
 if (firebaseUser) {
 console.log(firebaseUser);
 } else {
  $('#loginmessage').append(Message);
 console.log('not logged in');
 } // end else statement
 }); // end function
 });

// Clears all of the text-boxes for user login
  $("#emailLogin").val("");
  $("#passwordLogin").val("")
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `push` method expects an object as parameter.

Modify your call to this:

```
// the property names are up to you
database.ref().push({ email: emailnew, password: passwordnew });
```

Comment: Thanks! This resolved my call issue, and console log is showing entered values, but inputted data isn't populating in firebase. I think there is an issue with my calls but can't figure out what the problem is.